# Why would you have a css class that only modifies a single property?

Tags: css

I've often seen css with classes that only modify a single property. For example,

```
.ns-center-text{
    text-align: center;
}
```

What are the advantages and disadvantages of this technique?

Comment: Sure there is not a `.` preceding that selector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Advantages

- You can add a class in the HTML for quick and easy presentational things.
- You only have to add this declaration once in your CSS, instead of many times for each selector (or grouping a whole bunch of them).

#### Disadvantages

- You tie presentation to the *information* layer.
- You may end up with many classes on your elements.
- Classes should be descriptive of content, not their presentation.
- Have to touch the HTML to affect the website's presentation.

I'd recommend **against** using this.

Comment: "Classes should be descriptive of content, not their presentation." Sorry, can you elaborate: The entire purpose of stylesheets is about presentation. Also, what does this have to do with information layer? All he is asking about is a single CSS class with a single property. Having many classes on your elements may be a problem, yes, but it is a common technique in Grid layouts for structuring widths of elements. Also, a class like this can also be found in css files, does not have to be inline HTML. Not sure if I've missed something?

Comment: @DarylTeo: *The entire purpose of stylesheets is about presentation*, of course, but when you reference the class name in your HTML, you are *leaking* the presentation (`ns-center-text` class) to the HTML. What if you no longer want that element centred? You then have to modify the HTML, instead of the CSS which is more work than necessary and violates the single responsibility of each layer. Regarding Grid layouts, are you saying CSS grids that make you add classes such as `col_16` in the HTML are a good idea? They too leak presentational data to the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine them.

```
<div class="center block red one_third">
   ...
</div>
```

So you can mix and match properties for elements that have similar properties.

Answer (score 0):

Separation and consistency.

I prefer to have all CSS styles separated in a .css file, independent from the pages that they provide styles for, and this is a pattern I apply consistently.

It can get a bit messy when you start having a mixture of CSS specified in both .css files *and* as `style` attributes within pages.

Answer (score 0):

Maintenance in future and ease to change/add.